# Nvidia 325 driver

Tags: 13.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, ppa

I added [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) ppa and got this Drivers in my additional menu

[image]

I thought this ppa should provide proprietary drivers but in the menu I see **325 (open source)** so I have a question is this driver open source or propitiatory.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's proprietary.

If you install it, you will see that it is an NVidia official driver.

Probably a mistake in the xorg-edgers repo.